# Constructing matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to construct few matrices in MATLAB. Programming is not my forte and I cannot go into this. I know I should nest with for loops, but can't figure out how.I have an array of data y with T values. I need to set a lag m and then find Tm=T-2m+1. The  matrices Ymin and Yplus have order m x Tm, but don't know how to set them. In parentheses the position of the data in the array. Sorry for the format. The matrices are:

```
      y(m)      y(m+1)   ...   y(T-m)
      y(m-1)    y(m)     ...   y(T-m-1) 
        .
        .
        .
       y(1)      y(2)    ...   y(Tm)
```

and

```
      y(m+1)    y(m+2)     ...   y(T-m+1)
      y(m+2)    y(m+3)     ...   y(T-m-2) 
        .
        .
        .
       y(2m)      y(2m+1)  ...   y(T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following `matlab` code can help you!

```
%by Mark 4/28/2015

clear all;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% take an example

m=4; 
T=10;
y=zeros(1,T);

for i=1:(T)
    y(i)=i;
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% calculate Ymin

count_i=0;

for i=m:1:(T-m)

    count_i=count_i+1;

    count_j=0;

    for j=i:(-1):(i-m+1)
        count_j=count_j+1;
        Ymin(count_j,count_i)=y(j);
    end
end

Ymin

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% calculate Ymax

count_i=0;

for i=(m+1):1:(T-m+1)
    count_i=count_i+1;
    count_j=0;
    for j=i:1:(i+m-1)
        count_j=count_j+1;
        Ymax(count_j,count_i)=y(j);
    end
end

Ymax
```

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to Stackoverflow! If you indent your code 4 spaces in your answer, it will be properly formatted as code so it's easier to read. An easy way to do this is to select all of your code and press `ctrl-k`. That'll take care of all of it at one go.

Answer (score 3):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to get those two matrices -

```
T = numel(y) %// number of elements in y

idx1 = bsxfun(@plus,[m:-1:1]',0:Tm-1)
out1 = y(idx1)

idx2 = bsxfun(@plus,[m+1:2*m]',0:Tm-1)
out2 = y(idx2)
```

Comment: try making `T = numel(y)` into `Tm=numel(y)`

Comment: @andrew Well the question said `y` has `T` values. Also, in the question `Tm` is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hankel`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) or [`toeplitz`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) functions.

For first matrix use

```
flipud(hankel(y(1:m), y(m:Tm))
```

or

```
toeplitz(y(m:-1:1), y(m:Tm))
```

And for the second matrix use

```
hankel(y(m+1:2*m), y(2*m:T))
```